# nullpointerexception when request xml of nearbyplaces from google places api

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-xml, google-maps-api-2

I'm doing an application that request nearest places of certain type and return each result's name, coordinates and info in a list and i'm using google places api for this.

My code is as follows

**Helper.java** which has methods that sends a url to google server and retrieves an xml file and parses it to a list of Objects that holds the name, coordinates and info:

```
public Document getDocument(int radius, String type, LatLng current) {

        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?"
                + "location="
                + current.latitude
                + ","
                + current.longitude
                + "&radius="
                + radius
                + "&types="
                + type
                + "&sensor=true&key=MyKeyHere"; //i replace this with my api key

        Log.d("URL", url);

        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            Log.d("Document content", doc.getTextContent()); 
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyLocation> getNearbyLocations(Document doc) {
        Log.d("DOC**", doc.getTextContent());

        ArrayList<MyLocation> nearbyLocations = new ArrayList<MyLocation>();
        String name;
        double lati;
        double longi;
        String info;
        // MyLocation theLocation;

        NodeList nLName = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
        NodeList nLLat = doc.getElementsByTagName("lat");
        NodeList nLLong = doc.getElementsByTagName("lng");
        NodeList nLvicinity = doc.getElementsByTagName("vicinity");
        for (int i = 0; i < nLName.getLength(); i++) {

            name =  nLName.item(i).getNodeValue();
            lati =  Double.parseDouble(nLLat.item(i).getNodeValue());
            longi = Double.parseDouble(nLLong.item(i).getNodeValue());
            info =  nLvicinity.item(i).getNodeValue();
            nearbyLocations.add(new MyLocation(name, new LatLng(lati, longi),
                    info));
            Log.d("LIST***", nearbyLocations.toString());
        }

        return nearbyLocations;
    }
```

**Search.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);




        Helper= new Helper();


        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, ls);

        Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        ls.onLocationChanged(location);

     docu = Helper.getDocument(5000, "airport" ,new LatLng(alti, longi)); 
        nearByLocation= Helper.getNearbyLocations(docu); ////it gives me a nullpointerexception here

        //Log.d("DOC***", docu.getTextContent());

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list2);
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, getItems());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

the problem is that the program crashes when it calls the method getNearByLocations(doc), i think the problem is that the document retrieved is always null, so i dont know if my method of retrieving the XML file is wrong.

here is my logcat:

```
10-04 19:40:43.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1737): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 19:40:43.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.Gourp_KSA.tourfit.Helper.getNearbyLocations(Helper.java:95)
10-04 19:40:43.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at com.Gourp_KSA.tourfit.Search.onCreate(Search.java:85)
10-04 19:40:43.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-04 19:40:43.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-04 19:40:43.049: E/AndroidRuntime(1737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

***EDIT & ANSWER:

So i found what the problem was. It was that i was making a network connection on the main thread. I made an AsyncTask class to call the getNearbyLocations() method. I hope this helps***

Comment: Which line is `MapHelper.java:95`?

Comment: @ssantos it's Helper.java i made a mistake when making the question here i edit that now. And this is the line Log.d("DOC**",doc.getTextContent()); you can see it in the second method in Helper.java

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an HTTP POST request when I believe you should be sending HTTP GET requests to the Google Places API.

If you're interested in using a Java library that does all of this work for you and allows you to interact with the Google Places API through Java methods and objects, you can try [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets) (disclosure: I'm the developer).

The equivalent Sprockets call to get your `List` of `Place` objects would be:

```
Places.nearbySearch(Params.create().latitude(lat).longitude(lng)
        .radius(5000).types("airport")).getResult();
```

Comment: just went through your java library, it's really nice and is exactly what i need. I just can't seem to know how to add it to eclipse and use it in my program. Can you plz tell how to download and configure it?

Comment: Figured it out. Awesome job btw!

Comment: Thanks, I hope it's useful for you.  In the future I will be releasing a Sprockets Android library project that will hopefully make it easier to get going on Android if you're not using Maven or Gradle dependency resolution.